# Linux: Eclipse Internal web browser does not show html5 contents

Tags: linux, eclipse, html

I have a html page which uses the html5 canvas. When I open this page in Eclipse 4.5.2 on Windows and Mac OS Internal Web Browser it shows me the canvas and other things defined correctly. However when I tried the same on Linux (Eclipse 4.5.2) the internal web browser showed me all other contents except for the html5 canvas.
Please could you help me understand why the Linux variant of Eclipse does not show html5 contents in the internal web browser. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Eclipse just uses whatever browser is installed on your system, it does not have its own browser. See [the SWT FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with xulrunner version. 
I used the xulrunner version 24 and specified the following arguments in the vm arguments tab of the run launch configuration and it worked!

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType="mozilla"
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath="pathToXulRunner"

OR you can do that same by setting the System property through your java code

System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", "pathToXulRunner");
and then use the SWT.MOZILLA flag to create browser

eg Browser b = new Browser(parent, SWT.MOZILLA);

Cheers

-Kapil